# Inconsistencies between CultureInfo in Windows Universal

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-universal

I need generate a .CSV file from an UWP app so I'm using the TextInfo.ListSeparator.

I'm finding inconsistencies between the system settings and the value returned from code.

**Using Regional settings**:

[image]

**Using TextInfo Class**:

```
TextInfo textInfo = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textInfo.CultureName);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textInfo.IsReadOnly);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textInfo.ListSeparator);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(textInfo.IsRightToLeft);
```

[image]

My system is configured:

- Windows display language: English (United States)
- Region Format: Portuguese (Brazil)
- Region Home location: United States

**Edited**
As suggested in some answers, I rebooted my PC. Then a wrote an UWP and a Windows Forms app that uses the same code. And to compare I ran a Windows PowerShell. The values are still different as shown in the image below.

[image]

The PowerShell and the Windows Forms returned the expected results but the UWP fails.

Comment: I see the .NETCore runtime doing the right thing, it directly calls GetLocaleInfoEx() to obtain the Windows setting.  So it must be your machine config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works on my side.

I think it is because you didn't reopen your visual studio after you change the setting.

After you change the setting, it will not notify and force visual studio(or other apps) which are already opened to change their environment values. You have to close and reopen your visual studio to let visual studio starts with new settings.

[**Update**]

I got it working because I thought you just want to change the ListSeparator setting but didn't change the Region format. @user5596450 is on the right direction. So answer for your question is **no**. You cannot get the custom region format you specified in region settings.

Actually, the custom setting is not available for all device families. I believe the current result makes sense. What you expect should be provided by something like Desktop extension for UWP but not the .net core APIs. You can feel free to raise the request to wpdev.uservoice.com and Microsoft is listening developers feedback there.

**As an alternative**, .Net core API will check the PreferredLanguage for UWP app and get the corresponding settings to you. For example, if you call `Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride = "pt-br";` (generally in OnLaunched event in App.xaml.cs) in UWP app, you will get what you expect **but that is not from** the setting you customized in region setting. This is how it should work for universal app for different device family. Please take a look at [ApplicationLanguages.PrimaryLanguageOverride](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.applicationlanguages.primarylanguageoverride.aspx) MSDN doc to understand what it actually does.

FYI, CurrentCulture in .net core APIs that used by UWP can be found on [github](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Globalization/CultureInfo.cs). And here is how it is implemented:

```
public static CultureInfo CurrentCulture
{
    get
    {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<CultureInfo>() != null);

#if !FEATURE_CORECLR
        return Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
#else
                // In the case of CoreCLR, Thread.m_CurrentCulture and
                // Thread.m_CurrentUICulture are thread static so as not to let
                // CultureInfo objects leak across AppDomain boundaries. The
                // fact that these fields are thread static introduces overhead
                // in accessing them (through Thread.CurrentCulture). There is
                // also overhead in accessing Thread.CurrentThread. In this
                // case, we can avoid the overhead of Thread.CurrentThread
                // because these fields are thread static, and so do not
                // require a Thread instance to be accessed.
#if FEATURE_APPX
                if(AppDomain.IsAppXModel()) {
                    CultureInfo culture = GetCultureInfoForUserPreferredLanguageInAppX();
                    if (culture != null)
                        return culture;
                }
#endif
                return Thread.m_CurrentCulture ??
                    s_DefaultThreadCurrentCulture ??
                    s_userDefaultCulture ??
                    UserDefaultCulture;
#endif
    }

    set
    {
#if FEATURE_APPX
                    if (value == null) {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
                    }                    

                    if (AppDomain.IsAppXModel()) {
                        if (SetCultureInfoForUserPreferredLanguageInAppX(value)) {
                            // successfully set the culture, otherwise fallback to legacy path
                            return; 
                        }
                    }
#endif
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists even after restart the PC. Please, see my edited comment inside my question. Thank you

Comment: Check my update. @user5596450 is on right track. Simple answer for your question is no. but see if you can accept the alternative way.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the answer above is correct.  However, the more likely reason is that Win32 or System APIs use locale data based off of the specific Region Format setting (in this case pt-BR), which is ";".  UWP uses WinRT APIs, which use locale data based off of the Windows display language (in this case en-US), which is ",".

Comment: I made some tests to validate your suggestion and it makes sense. Please, see my edited comment inside my question. Thank you